# Vuejs 3 vite with module federation share store between modules

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, vite, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

We want to create an application and want to spilt it into modules with the help of module federation.

The idea is that each module can live alone (without the host). For this requirement, we have to implement the routing and the store in each module.

In the host, we want to merge all stores, so that we can also have access to each store if needed.

is this possible? or how should we share the store/state between the modules?

for example, I have an authentication module, where the login logic is in place. This will call a backend, get user information like JWT token, and store this in the store.

vite.config of the host

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
    
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
    import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
    import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
    import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
    const APPLICATION_PORT = 5000;
    export default defineConfig({
      build: {
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
        target: "esnext",
      },
      server: {
        port: APPLICATION_PORT,
      },
      preview: {
        port: APPLICATION_PORT,
      },
      plugins: [
        vue(),
        vueJsx(),
        federation({
          name: "container",
          filename: "container.js",
          exposes: {
            "./router": "./src/router/index.js",
          },
          remotes: {
            // ToDo: define modules for the application
            login: "http://localhost:5001/assets/login.js",
          },
          shared: ["vue", "vue-router", "vuex"]
        }),
      ],
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
      }});
    
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/
```

config of the remote

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation';

const APPLICATION_PORT = 5001;
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    target: "esnext",
  },
  server: {
    port: APPLICATION_PORT,
  },
  preview: {
    port: APPLICATION_PORT,
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    // vueJsx(),
    federation({
      name: "login",
      filename: "login.js",
      exposes: {
        "./routes": "./src/router/routes.js",
        "./store": "./src/store/index.js",
        "./App": "./src/App.vue",
        "./login": "./src/views/LoginView.vue",
        "./forgotPassword": "./src/views/ForgotPasswordView.vue",
      },

      shared: ["vue", "vue-router", "vuex"],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

The routing works well, so I have configured the routes in the authentication module, but I cannot access the store. I get the following error:

```
[vuex] unknown mutation type: login
commit @ vuex.esm-bundler.js:999
boundCommit @ vuex.esm-bundler.js:940
handleLogin @ __federation_expose_Login-3643b6d2.js:3297
await in handleLogin (async)
_createElementVNode.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> @ __federation_expose_Login-3643b6d2.js:3400
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:278
Show 5 more frames
Show less
```

the store is visible in the chrome vue extension.
and i have configured the store like this:

```
import loginStore from "login/store";
const containerStore = createStore({
    modules: {
        login: loginStore
    }
})

app.use(containerStore);
```

Comment: Did you solve it yet? I probably don‘t want to do something similar, because it could mean coupling, but maybe there are use cases where it could become handy